# Access property using a variable path

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure I formed the title correctly since Google keeps silence on it.

I want to access a property (or an object, or an instance) by using path, consisting of known path + variable path. Let's say there are 5 properties: pr1, pr2... pr5. For rehearsal them I use:

`for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++) {...}`

Next I want to get the property, using `i`. Something like this: `self.pr+i;`. What is the correct way to do it in Objective C?

Comment: What are the properties? Show the code for them. And what are you using them for once you have them?

Comment: Remember to vote for the answer that solved your problem ;-)

Comment: Wain, I'm below 15 points yet and not able to vote :(

Answer (score 2):

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i <=5; i++)
{
 // access read
    id property = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pr%ld",(long)i]];

  // write
    id someValue;
    [self setValue:someValue forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pr%ld",(long)i]];

  // remember pr1 must be a self property.
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. (Voted) You can also use `valueForKeyPath`, which will traverse multiple objects, like `self.dictionary.key.property`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, though you don't describe the exact case, you can use KVC:

```
id myVar = [self valueForKey:myVarName];
```

so once you know that you just need to create the string:

```
NSString *myVarName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pr%d", i];
```